# How to save names of files operated on in function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

I have a python function that performs operations on each text file in a folder. I want to save the name of each file operated on so that the function returns the file name along with other results.

I tried various methods shown below.

This gets all the file names, but for all of the files in each iteration instead of the single file being operated on.

```
import re, glob, os, pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def sections(file_name):    


    with open(file_name,'r') as f:  
        text = f.read()

        doc = textacy.preprocess.normalize_whitespace(text)
        votes = re.findall(r"Voting[\s*]\D+.+", doc)
        provisions = re.findall(r"Provisions+([\s\S]*?)(?=authorized)", doc)
        name = os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]        

        return name, board, votes, provisions


file_dir = Path(r"path")  
all_files = file_dir.glob("*.txt")  
results = [sections(f) for f in all_files]

print(results)
```

this works, but hasn't worked in function and would be better to obtain from function than combining with results.

```
files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.txt", recursive=True)]

files = pd.DataFrame(files)
files.columns = ['file_name']
files['file_name'] = files['file_name'].replace(r'.*(?=\\).','', regex=True)
```

When the function returns I want the file name to be included with the other variables.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: Are you sure your function is returning the entire set of files in each iteration? `os.path.splitext(file_name)[0]` will return the extentionless name of a single file. And this is returned by your function.. so no multiple files here. What I see in the end is that you're printing an array of returns of function `sections(file_name)`.. and there you will get, among other stuff in the return statement, the name of all the files you've operated on. Am I right?

Comment: @AlexandreJuma yes and now I have printed again to csv and see it works correctly - unsure of what went wrong before. thank you